# VueJS - calling method in v-for loop, get error 'not defined on the instance but referenced during render'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a Vue noobie (Vuebie?) I know this has been asked before but I haven't found a solution.

I am trying pass an object to method to += a value and display a total value.

I either get a `method / prop not defined on instance but referenced during render` error or variations of undefined variable errors.

This template is nested several levels deep in other templates so I'm not sure how / where to define my `getCollectionsTotal` method.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="c-filter__list" v-if="categories.length">
      <li
        class="c-filter__list__items"
        v-for="(category, index) in categories"
        :key="index"
        @click.stop="setCurrentCategory(category)"
      >
        {{ getCollectionTotal(category) }} // pass the category object to my method
        <a
          v-bind:class="{
            'is-selected': filters.category.includes(category.category_name)
          }"
          class="c-link c-link--filter"
          >{{ category.category_name }}
          <span>({{ category.collections_number }})</span> 
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="collectionsTotal">{{ collectionsTotal }}</div> // display the total here
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import state from "../store/index";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "categories-sidebar",
  computed: mapState(["filters", "categories"]),
  methods: {
    setCurrentCategory: function(category) {
      if (this.filters) {
        this.filters.category.includes(category.category_name)
          ? state.commit("delCategory", category.category_name)
          : state.commit("setCategory", category.category_name);
      }
    },
    getCollectionTotal(cat) {
      let collectionsTotal; // this says 'assigned a value but never used'
      collectionsTotal += cat.collections_number;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: the code in `getCollectionTotal` is equivalent to `let collectionsTotal = undefined + cat.collections_number` and then completely ignoring this result, and returning `undefined` - i.e the code in that function may as well be absent altogether ...  may as well be `getCollectionTotal() {   }`

Comment: the error is due to `collectionsTotal` not being defined anywhere as a prop or data or computed etc value ... it's simply undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `mapState` in a correct way.
Change this:

`computed: mapState(["filters", "categories"])`

into

`computed: { ...mapState(["filters", "categories"]) }`

*For further information, you can check:*

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dont-understand-how-to-use-mapstate-from-the-docs/14454

Comment: the syntax is correct because there are mergin inside the computed property.

Answer (score 0):

You should to return something from your function and assign a initial value to your collectionsTotal variable:

```
getCollectionTotal(cat) {
  let collectionsTotal = ''; // or let collectionsTotal = 0;
  collectionsTotal += cat.collections_number;
  return collectionsTotal;
}
```